# В чем отличие способов создание потоков?

Tags: c++, winapi

Я не силен в си,так что не накидывайтесь на меня.
Объясните в чем отличие способов создания потоков?

```
HANDLE mainThread = CreateThread(0, 0, &MainThread, 0, 0, 0);
```

или

```
thread swt(switcher);
swt.detach();
```

И почему я не могу в CreateThread указать любую void функцию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

если коротко, то CreateThread это winapi функция в общем и целом к языку программирования не имеющая отношения, а std::thread - реализация многопоточной работы библиотекой С++.

Касаемо void функции, это требование api
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread

В качестве функции передается коллбэк заранее описанного вида

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(
  _In_ LPVOID lpParameter
);
```

см. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms686736(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 1):

С++ `thread` на в конечном счете вызовет `CreateThread`. Это сделает C++ Runtime. Под Linux это будет `pthread`. То есть, в каждой OS различные функции C++ (потоки, обработка файлов и т. д.) переводятся в функции данной OS (native OS API).

Если пишете на C++, лучше использовать `thread`. Использование `CreateThread` сразу сделает невозможной компиляцию программы под другой операционкой.